# Unittest: How do I get the values that have been passed to a patch decorator?

Tags: python-unittest

Is there something (I can get the value of) in `patch`, `test_posting`, or `mock_post` that will tell me what values were passed to the original `requests.post` (or maybe there's some other way)?

The service function looks like this:

```
def post_to_api_server():
    response = requests.post('{}{}'.format(API_SERVER_URL, SEARCH_PATH),
                             data=payload, headers=header_json, verify=False)
    if response.ok:
        return response
    else:
        return None
```

The test function looks like this:

```
@patch('requests.post')
def test_posting(mock_post):
    mock_post.return_value = Mock(ok=True)
    mock_post.return_value.json.return_value = my_test_json
    response = post_to_api_server()
```

Comment: Have you tried `mock_post.call_args`?

Comment: `print(mock_post.call_args, file=f)` comes back as `None`.

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing the actual code...

Comment: `requests.post.call_args` also gets `None`. Maybe I can `start` the mock after I get the call args.

Comment: `None` means that it has not been called yet - you have to check it after it has been called in the test, of course. Maybe you just add a bit more code to your question to show what you are doing.

Comment: mock_post.call_args works after the `response = post_to_api_server()` call! Which was what you were saying all along. :-/

Comment: There are some `assert_called...` methods that you can use to check for the correct call - check the documentation of `unittest.Mock`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a hint from @mrbean-bremmen, add something like this after the call to `response = post_to_api_server()`:

```
    args_tuple, kwargs_dict = mock_post.call_args
    url = args_tuple[0]
    if 'data' in kwargs_dict:
        data = kwargs_dict['data']
    if 'json' in kwargs_dict:
        json = kwargs_dict['json']
```